# How To Register Only One Mouse Click - Pygame

Tags: python, events, pygame, mouse

I'm making a game in Pygame with an upgrade system. After each round, the player is taken to an upgrade screen to click on stats they want to upgrade using the points they collected. However, if the player has enough points for the first upgrade and clicks the ATK upgrade, it will upgrade the attack and then check the loop again. So if the player has enough points for the second upgrade as well, my program runs the upgrade the second time without the player clicking the button twice.

What can I do to register only one click so my program doesn't spend every point possible in one click?

UPDATE: I've found that if I click the upgrade button really quickly then it registers as one click but if it is held any longer than a split second it repeats the "click". Does anyone know how to just have an input of one click when the mouse button is pressed and then released?

Button Class Logic:

```
if x + width > mouse_pos[0] > x and y + height > mouse_pos[1] > y:    
    text_to_button(message, color, x, y, width, height)

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and action != None:
```

Actual Button:

```
button("ATK", RED, D_RED, 110, 280, 145, 50, action = "ATK")
```

ATK Upgrade Logic:

```
if action == "ATK":
    if player.attack == 1 and up_points >= 3:
        player.attack += .5
        up_points -= 3
    elif player.attack == 1.5 and up_points >= 6:
        player.attack += .5
        up_points -= 6
```

FULL (relevant) CODE:

```
def button(message, color, color_d, x, y, width, height, action = "nothing"):
    global main_menu
    global control_menu
    global how_to_play_menu
    global gameplay
    global upgrade_screen

    global game_timer
    global score
    global up_points
    global Max_ammo
    global ammo
    global ammo_refill
    global reload_time
    global Max_range
    global shoot_range
    global ms
    global attack
    global defence
    global current_health
    global reloading
    global up_points

    global a
    global d
    global m
    global am
    global re
    global ra

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (x, y, width, height))

    if x + width > mouse_pos[0] > x and y + height > mouse_pos[1] > y:

        text_to_button(message, color, x, y, width, height)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action != "nothing":
            if action == "quit game":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if action == "controls":
                main_menu = False
                how_to_play_menu = False
                control_menu = True

            if action == "how to play":
                main_menu = False
                how_to_play_menu = True
                control_menu = False

            if action == "back":
                main_menu = True
                control_menu = False
                how_to_play_menu = False

            if action == "ATK":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if player.attack == 1 and up_points >= 5:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 5
                    a = "8 UP"
                elif player.attack == 1.5 and up_points >= 8:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 8
                    a = "12 UP"
                elif player.attack == 2 and up_points >= 12:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 12
                    a = "15 UP"
                elif player.attack == 2.5 and up_points >= 15:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 15
                    a = "18 UP"
                elif player.attack == 3 and up_points >= 18:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 18
                    a = "23 UP"
                elif player.attack == 3.5 and up_points >= 23:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 23
                    a = "27 UP"
                elif player.attack == 4 and up_points >= 27:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 27
                    a = "32 UP"
                elif player.attack == 4.5 and up_points >= 32:
                    player.attack += .5
                    up_points -= 32
                    a = "MAXED"


            if action == "DEF":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if player.defence == 1 and up_points >= 4:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 4
                    d = "8 UP"
                elif player.defence == 1.5 and up_points >= 8:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 8
                    d = "12 UP"
                elif player.defence == 2 and up_points >= 12:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 12
                    d = "16 UP"
                elif player.defence == 2.5 and up_points >= 16:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 16
                    d = "20 UP"
                elif player.defence == 3 and up_points >= 20:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 20
                    d = "23 UP"
                elif player.defence == 3.5 and up_points >= 23:
                    player.defence += .5
                    up_points -= 23
                    d = "MAXED"

            if action == "MS":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if ms == 2 and up_points >= 4:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 5
                    m = "8 UP"
                elif ms == 2.5 and up_points >= 8:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 8
                    m = "12 UP"
                elif ms == 3 and up_points >= 12:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 12
                    m = "17 UP"
                elif ms == 3.5 and up_points >= 17:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 17
                    m = "24 UP"
                elif ms == 4 and up_points >= 24:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 24
                    m = "30 UP"
                elif ms == 4.5 and up_points >= 30:
                    ms += .5
                    up_points -= 30
                    m = "MAXED"

            if action == "AMMO":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if Max_ammo == 3 and up_points >= 8:
                    Max_ammo += 1
                    up_points -= 8
                    am = "12 UP"
                elif Max_ammo == 4 and up_points >= 12:
                    Max_ammo += 1
                    up_points -= 12
                    am = "16 UP"
                elif Max_ammo == 5 and up_points >= 16:
                    Max_ammo += 1
                    up_points -= 16
                    am = "20 UP"
                elif Max_ammo == 6 and up_points >= 20:
                    Max_ammo += 1
                    up_points -= 20
                    am = "25 UP"
                elif Max_ammo == 7 and up_points >= 25:
                    Max_ammo += 1
                    up_points -= 25
                    am = "MAXED"

            if action == "RELOAD":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if reload_time == 2 and up_points >= 4:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 4
                    re = "7 UP"
                elif reload_time == 2.5 and up_points >= 7:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 7
                    re = "11 UP"
                elif reload_time == 3 and up_points >= 11:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 11
                    re = "15 UP"
                elif reload_time == 3.5 and up_points >= 15:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 15
                    re = "18 UP"
                elif reload_time == 4 and up_points >= 18:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 18
                    re = "22 UP"
                elif reload_time == 4.5 and up_points >= 22:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 22
                    re = "26 UP"
                elif reload_time == 5 and up_points >= 26:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 26
                    re = "30 UP"
                elif reload_time == 5.5 and up_points >= 30:
                    reload_time += .5
                    up_points -= 30
                    re = "MAXED"

            if action == "RANGE":
                pygame.time.wait(150)
                if Max_range == 10 and up_points >= 5:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 5
                    ra = "9 UP"
                elif Max_range == 16 and up_points >= 9:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 9
                    ra = "13 UP"
                elif Max_range == 22 and up_points >= 13:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 13
                    ra = "17 UP"
                elif Max_range == 28 and up_points >= 17:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 17
                    ra = "20 UP"
                elif Max_range == 34 and up_points >= 20:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 20
                    ra = "24 UP"
                elif Max_range == 40 and up_points >= 24:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 24
                    ra = "28 UP"
                elif Max_range == 46 and up_points >= 28:
                    Max_range += 6
                    up_points -= 28
                    ra = "32 UP"
                elif Max_range == 52 and up_points >= 32:
                    Max_range += 8
                    up_points -= 32
                    ra = "MAXED"

            if action == "start": # VERY IMPORTANT!! This if statement resets the game when the
                main_menu = False # player presses "START" in the main menu. Everything will be
                                  # reset to these values WHEN THE PLAYER STARTS A NEW GAME

                game_timer = 1280
                score = 0
                up_points = 1500 # change to 0
                Max_ammo = 3
                ammo = Max_ammo
                ammo_refill = (0)
                reload_time = 2
                player.current_health = 210
                player.attack = 1
                player.defence = 1
                ms = 2
                Max_range = 10
                bullet.shoot_range = Max_range
                reloading = False
                a = "5 UP"
                d = "4 UP"
                m = "4 UP"
                am = "8 UP"
                re = "4 UP"
                ra = "5 UP"
                player.rect.x = int(screen_width / 2)
                player.rect.y = int(screen_height / 2) + 200
                player.change_x = 0
                player.change_y = 0
                all_sprites_list.add(player)

                for i in range(5):
                    zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
                    all_sprites_list.add(zombie)
                    zombie_list.add(zombie)

                gameplay = True



    else:
        text_to_button(message, color_d, x, y, width, height)




pygame.init()

screen_size = pygame.display.Info()

size = (1300, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#size = (screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode(((screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)),pygame.FULLSCREEN)

screen_width = 1300     #screen_size.current_w
screen_height = 720    #screen_size.current_h

pygame.display.set_caption("HOARD")

wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombie_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
up_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Walls are made here = (x_coord for where it starts,
# y_coord for where it starts, width of wall, height of wall)
# These walls are made with fullscreen dimentions, not any set dimentions
# Left
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, 10, screen_height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# Top
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# Bottom
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 10, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# Right
wall = Wall(BLUE, screen_width - 10, 0, 10, screen_width)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# HUD Border
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 100, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)


player = Player(WHITE)
player.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(player)

zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
zombie.walls = wall_list


cursor = Cursor(7, 7)
cursor.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(cursor)

bullet = Bullet()
up = Up(zombie.rect.center)


tiny_font = pygame.font.Font("/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/Python Programs/Pygame 3.5/HOARD/hypefonts_crushed/crushed.ttf", 15)
small_font = pygame.font.Font("/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/Python Programs/Pygame 3.5/HOARD/hypefonts_crushed/crushed.ttf", 25)
med_font = pygame.font.Font("/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/Python Programs/Pygame 3.5/HOARD/hypefonts_crushed/crushed.ttf", 45)
big_font = pygame.font.Font("/Users/tannerbeeson/Documents/Python Programs/Pygame 3.5/HOARD/hypefonts_crushed/crushed.ttf", 80)


done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

main_menu = True
gameplay = False
control_menu = False
how_to_play_menu = False
upgrade_screen = False




# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    while gameplay:

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

        # --- Actual Gameplay Loop ---
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            # Press 'Escape' to exit the game_____
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    for i in zombie_list:
                        i.kill()
                    for i in up_list:
                        i.kill()
                    for i in bullet_list:
                        i.kill()
                    for i in all_sprites_list:
                        if i is player:
                            player.kill()
                    gameplay = False
                    main_menu = True


            # Keyboard controls. The numbers inside change the speed of the player
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and (player.alive()):
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.movement(-ms, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.movement(ms, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.movement(0, -ms)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.movement(0, ms)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    player.change_x = 0
                    player.change_y = 0
                    pause()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP and (player.alive()):
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.movement(ms, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.movement(-ms, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.movement(0, ms)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.movement(0, -ms)

            # Shooting / Reloading Logic

            elif not reloading and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and ammo > 0 and (player.alive()):
                ammo -= 1
                bullet = Bullet()
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0, 0, 1) and player.alive() and ammo != Max_ammo and reloading != True:
                reloading = True
#--------------------------------------

        # Reloading Animation
        if reloading == True:
            ammo = 0
            ammo_refill += reload_time
            if ammo_refill >= 200:
                reloading = False
                ammo = Max_ammo
                ammo_refill = 0

        # Gameplay Timer Speed and Animation
        if gameplay == True and player.alive():
            game_timer -= 100 # Change to 1
            if game_timer <= -10:
                end_round()
                break



        # Mouse Controls----------------------------
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cursor_x = pos[0]
        cursor_y = pos[1]

        if cursor_x <= 10:
            cursor_x = 10
        if cursor_x >= (screen_width - 17):
            cursor_x = (screen_width - 17)

        if cursor_y <= 10:
            cursor_y = 10
        if cursor_y >= (screen_height - 107):
            cursor_y = (screen_height - 107)
        #-------------------------------------------

        # If the player falls off the map, kill them
        if (player.rect.x >= screen_width or player.rect.x <= 0) or (player.rect.y >= screen_height or player.rect.y <= 0):
            player.kill()

        all_sprites_list.update()

        # How bullets vanish when they hit something______________________________
        for shot in bullet_list:
            shot.shoot_range -= 1
            if shot.shoot_range <= 0:
                shot.kill()

            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, zombie_list, False)
            for z in block_hit_list:
                z.hp -= player.attack
                bullet.kill()
                if z.hp <= 0:
                    z.kill()
                    bullet.kill()
                    score += 100
                    if random.randrange(1, 11) >= 8:
                        Up(z.rect.center).add(all_sprites_list, up_list)
                        if random.randrange(1, 3) == 2:
                            Up(z.rect.center).add(all_sprites_list, up_list)


        for bullet in bullet_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, wall_list, False)
            for i in block_hit_list:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for point in up_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, up_list, True)
            for point in block_hit_list:
                up.kill()
                up_points += 1

        if player.current_health < 0:
            player.kill()


        # .update() will 'update' or change the screen with what
        # we've told it to everytime we run throught the loop. Without
        # this our player would not appear to move on the screen because
        # we wouldn't be telling the screen to change the coordinates of the player.
        all_sprites_list.update()
        bullet_list.update()
        cursor.update()

        # Drawing commands: What you actually see happening (along with update commands)
        screen.fill(BLACK)

        # HUD
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, HUD_GREY, [10, screen_height - 90, screen_width, 80])

        score_text = small_font.render("SCORE: " + str(score), True, PURPLE)
        screen.blit(score_text, [20, screen_height - 64])

        up_text = small_font.render("UP: " + str(up_points), True, YELLOW)
        screen.blit(up_text, [365, screen_height - 64])

        ammo_text = small_font.render("AMMO: " + str(ammo), True, ORANGE)
        screen.blit(ammo_text, [1014, screen_height - 74])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [1017, screen_height - 43, 200, 15])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ORANGE, [1018, screen_height - 43, float(ammo_refill), 15])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ORANGE, [1018, screen_height - 43, float(ammo / Max_ammo) * 200, 15])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [1017, screen_height - 43, 200, 15], 2)

        health_text = small_font.render("HEALTH:", True, GREEN)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [745, screen_height - 70, 220, 40])
        screen.blit(health_text, [560, screen_height - 64])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [745, screen_height - 70, 220, 40], 3)

        # Game Timer
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [9, screen_height - 20, game_timer + 1, 10])

        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

        # Player Health
        if player.alive() == True:
            if player.taking_damage == True:
                pygame.Surface.fill(screen, RED, [750, screen_height - 65, int(player.current_health), 30], 5)
            else:
                pygame.Surface.fill(screen, GREEN, [750, screen_height - 65, int(player.current_health), 30], 5)


        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Each click is already a separate event.  How are you getting the event?

Comment: @cmd If I hold the mouse button down, the even continues to happen over and over again. I want to make one event happen for one click, not 3 for one click.

Comment: Actually that is not true.  You get one `MouseButtonDown` when you click the mouse even if you wait a minute before releasing, then you get one `MouseButtonUp` when you let go.

Comment: @cmd Actually, _that's_ not true. I wouldn't be posting this question if what you just said was working :P As long as the mouse button is down, it recognizes a click as true which is not what I want, I just want one instance of a click when I press down and then release, not as many instances it can produce for as long as the button is held down

Comment: If that is what you are observing then you are doing something wrong.  Where is `event` in function `button` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your full code, but I guess your problem is using `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` somewhere where you should simpy check for the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`  event.

Each mouseclick generates one `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event; but if you check `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` inside a loop, you see the button pressed for multiple iterations of that loop (if you're not fast enough to release the mouse button).

Note that the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event has a `button` attribute, which you can use to check which button was pressed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, if I hold the mouse down it still registers the button as being down over and over. I've posted my full code above so you can look through it. It over 1000 lines but the functions are at the top below my classes

Comment: Just kidding, it wouldn't fit in the body so I included the relevant parts. For now I have the screen pausing after clicking an upgrade so that way it only has time to register one click. It works for now but I'd like a one click system instead of this ghetto work around haha :P

Comment: Where is the `button` function actually called? I guess the `event` variable you use in that function is a global variable and you call `button` multiple times instead of once.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to this but adding a

```py
time.sleep()
```

worked for me.

EDIT: the line above stops or pauses the entire program for a fixed duration. Ideally, you do not want that to happen in your game. Instead one can use a builtin pygame function:

```
pygame.time.wait(x)
```

where x is in *milliseconds* (1000 millisecond = 1 second). This code does not pause your game loop.